# How do I save and archive a CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, coordinates, cllocationcoordinate2d

In my app I am creating, the user drops a pin on the map, and saves it. The coordinates of the pin are saved as a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` coordinate. Here is my code-

```
@IBAction func saveItem(_ sender: AnyObject?) {

    let itemName = itemNameTextField.text!
    let itemDescription = itemDescriptionLabel.text!
    let itemLocation = itemLocationTextView.text!
    let point = dropPin.coordinate

    if itemName == "" {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "The Item Name!", message:"You have not entered an item name. Please enter a name before saving.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if itemDescription == "" {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "The Description!", message:"You have not entered a description for your item. Please enter a description before saving.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    if itemLocation == "" {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "The Item Location!", message:"You have not entered the location of your item. Please do so before saving. Marking the loction on teh map is not necessary, but it is recommended.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Got It!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)


        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    else{

        item = itemData(itemName:itemName, itemDescription:itemDescription, itemPlace:itemLocation, mapPoint:point)
        print("Item name: \(itemName), Item Description: \(itemDescription), Item Location: \(itemLocation)")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveUnwind", sender: self)

    }
}
```

However, when the user saves, I get an error like this- `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170c552d0'`. Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: what arguments gets itemData function?

Comment: Where are you trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says, use an `NSValue` to wrap your coordinate.
It looks like there is a ready-made NSValue wrapper for a coordinate:

Take a look at the `NSValue` initializer

```
init(mkCoordinate:)
```

That lets you convert a `CLCoordinate2D` to an `NSValue`, which you can then write directly to an archive.

Answer (score -1):

To use NSCoding you have to conform to NSObject and NSCoding.
Example:

```swift
import CoreLocation

class LocationCoordinateWrapper: NSObject, NSCoding  {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let lat = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "lat")
        let lon = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "lon")
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let lat = coordinate?.latitude, let lon = coordinate?.longitude {
            aCoder.encode(lat, forKey: "lat")
            aCoder.encode(lon, forKey: "lon")
        }
    }
}

let wrapper = LocationCoordinateWrapper(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 14.0, longitude: -71.0))

let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let filePath = documentsPath.appending("/sample_filename.loc")

NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(wrapper, toFile: filePath) // saves to a file
let loaded = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? LocationCoordinateWrapper // loads back in the file
```

Comment: True but pointless, since there is already a location coordinate wrapper, namely NSValue.

Comment: I am using NSCoding, and this is basically exactly what I did. I just didn't include that code.